# Saving my Fetched JSON data on the android phone

Tags: android, json, saving-data

My android app is a news app that fetches JSON data as its content from a link.... I want the user to be able to store these contents on their android phone app directory for future viewing... Please how can I do this?

Comment: You can parse the Json and save the data in a local database. Using Shared Preferences is an alternative, but if user clears the app data, then data stored in Shared Preferences will be cleared as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are asking, but it seems you want to store data in your app to the phone for quick access?

There are a few ways of doing this:

### [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

This is more for settings saved in the app in a key value pair style. You can save just about anything, though I wouldn't suggest it for long blocks of text as its main usage seems to be for small variable persistence.

### [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

This is good for file storage. Probably a little closer to what you are looking for though it may be a little too intensive for something as storing blocks of text from news articles.

### [External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Much the same as internal storage though through the SD card. This is also a file storage system.

### [SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

This would store all the data to a sqliteDB on the phone. This might be closer to what you are looking for if you have a bunch of articles to store and quickly access. This method might require some more work than the others but will probably be a better method in the long run.

### [Network](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#netw)

This is what you are doing to pull the data and probably not what you want to use to store it if you want to store it locally, but for others reading this. This would allow you to pull and push data from the net.

Here is a link to all of the [Android storage options.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

And make you json object implementing Parcelable

See [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Answer (score 0):

Store data

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DATA_FILE", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsE = prefs.edit();
    String data = "some data I want to store on the phone for future use.";
    prefsE.putString("NAMETOSAVEDATAUNDER", data);
    prefsE.commit();
```

Get stored data

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("DATA_FILE", 0);
    String data = prefs.getString("NAMETOSAVEDATAUNDER", null);
```

Comment: You can do much more than just strings to just check out the shared preferences documentation